# How to handle expired Facebook oauth tokens in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook gives a clear example of how to handle expired tokens in php: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500 . Does anyone have code to the same thing in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the example does in your posted blog link is to attempt to query the graph and if that fails it reconnects the user. And in the JavaScript SDK this is handled by [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

For Example:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    if (response.error && response.error.type == "OAuthException" ) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            ....
        }, {scope: 'YOUR,REQUIRED,PERMISSIONS'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey jBit, correct me if I'm wrong, but each time you call FB.login, you are taken out of your app and into the Facebook app where you have to click "Okay". This means, each time your token expires (every 2 hours), you must put the user out of your app and into Facebook to press "Okay"?